# Removing Limitation of Cell (Dropdown menu)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In particular column in ALL cells I have dropdown menu. Each cell contains it and those dropdown menus must stay there in every single cell of the same column. All of the options within dropdown menu are by far over 5 charachters long. However the point is that those dropdown menus are only suggesting me the value and don't yet provide the actual final value. When i pick wanted option from dropdown menu, I want to edit it and delete at least 80% of value size. However I am getting error message that value entered isn't valid and that user has limited value that may be entered. I think word "limited" is referred to size. Is there any way that I could keep in cell MUCH lower value (in size) than average size of all options in dropdown menu are BUT at the same time keep the actual dropdown menu so it still exist in each cell of the column? I have excel 2013 pro. Thank you!

Comment: This is not very well explained.  Please clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - no. You cannot type in a 5 letter abbreviation, when the dropdown list asks for, say, a list of words that are 6 letters long.

If displaying the full selection is important but you can't change the column size, consider:

-Adjusting your source list so that it shows abbreviations instead of full words [If you include both abbreviations and full words, this might help the user get the point]; OR

-Changing the font size of the column to be smaller; OR

-Wrapping the text in the box so that it shows as multiple rows if the answer is longer.

Comment: I deleted in every cell of column dropdown menu. Saved, reopened and dropdown menus are now gone in particular column. However limitation is still here.. I still cannot define any size value inside. Error still User has limited values that may be entered inside this cell.